# NSUserDefault not load prefs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, preferences

I have class Prefs.m with methods:

```
+ (void) setString:(NSString *)valor chave:(NSString *)chave{

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [prefs setObject:valor forKey:chave];

    [prefs synchronize];
}

+ (NSString *) getString:(NSString *)chave{

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *valor = [prefs stringForKey:chave];

    return valor;
}
```

And I set the preferences in the class LoginController.m :

```
//Guarda informações do usuário no NSUserDefault
  [Prefs setString:strID chave:@"prefID"];
  [Prefs setString:usrNome chave:@"prefNome"];
  [Prefs setString:usrEmail chave:@"prefEmail"];
```

But when I load the prefs in the class IndicationViewController.m :

```
//Busca por informações do usuário se não tem o ID na prefs
 int intID = [Prefs getInteger:@"prefID"];
```

Return value = 0. But in the set prefs, the value was 1. Why?

Comment: It looks like you're setting a string, but getting back an integer.

Comment: What does the `Prefs getInteger:` method look like?  You're setting a string for the key @"prefID" and trying to pull an int out.

Comment: Also, can you show how you're setting `strID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
int intID = [Prefs getInteger:@"prefID"];
```

To this:

```
int intID = [[Prefs getString:@"prefID"] intValue];
```

Or to this:

```
NSString *prefID = [Prefs getString:@"prefID"];
```